# In-House Distribution Apple Tips (Help)

Tags: ios, app-distribution

Can some one explain to me how can i distribute mobile app outside the Apple Store?I preferred via Website .The application is for factory workers not for public use.

Comment: As I know there is two way. One is to share via uploading it to iTunes Connect and releasing as beta test. Other one (which I use always) is to get  register devices in your account and create new provision file for that then distribute with http://diawi.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about app distribution and not directly programming related.

Comment: So what if it's not a programing question, it's still a my job to distribute the app! @Abizern

Comment: I appreciate that it is something you need to do, but that doesn't mean that this is the correct forum to ask these questions. Not only is this off-topic because it's about app distribution policies and not programming, but also because it's a really broad question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all these workers are part of the same company, you'll want the [Enterprise Distribution program](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html), which allows you to distribute to anyone with the correct certificate, bypassing the store and UDID gathering.

If they don't all work for the same company, then any workaround is outside the terms of your development license - you can't bypass the App Store and setup an adhoc sales process (well, you can, but how long your development account will work is another matter). However, it's fine to have your app in the store, even if it's for a niche market. There's no "Must be applicable to every iOS owner" restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc installation is the best-- add all of your factory devices on IOS Developer portal on the Devices Section

> each device has its own UDID. That's how you separate them

Then export the app as ad-hoc, it'll give you an IPA. Upload it on somewhere like [Pgyer.com](https://pgyer.com)

Spread the link!

Comment: This isn't suitable as there may be more than 100 factory workers and each time a new employee starts at the factory their device id will need adding to the profile and a new build. Adam Wright is correct to suggest the Enterprise Distribution program.

Comment: I am sorry, he didn't mentioned that their company holds more than one hundred workers.. and I was just helping,

Comment: Hey no need to be sorry! It's a good idea, it's just that there's a solution built especially for this :)